# LLVM vs GCC MIPS code generation, any benchmarks?

Tags: gcc, assembly, benchmarking, mips, llvm

I'm interested in knowing what is "best" free/OSS compiler for MIPS code, GCC or LLVM, or is there anything even better than those?

I'm interested in knowing more about fast and memory constrained generated Assembly code than code size.

In other words, does llvm-opt do the job better than gcc -O3?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but afaik LLVM does a better job than GCC on x86.

Comment: Why would you say so? From the benchmarks I see, LLVM 2.4 is tightly close to GCC 4.2 and I've never seen a benchmark against GCC 4.3. And when GCC 4.4 is out with a new optimization framework will LLVM 2.5 be better? or basically almost the same?

Comment: AFAIK well-done GCC vs LLVM comparisons are quite few in general (as opposed to blanket statements on their mailing lists based on anecdotal evidence). Your best bet is to do comparison yourself, on the code that is relevant for you.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OTI1MA
"LLVM 2.9 Release Candidate 2 Is Here

Posted by Michael Larabel on March 25, 2011
no LLVM ARM benchmarks due to lack of hardware..."

perhaps someone with a fast dual/quad arm cortex and LLVM ARM etc can run a http://openbenchmarking.org/ bench before monday and Michael can add these to his other results

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about mips, I tried ARM and llvm code was around 10-20% slower than the current gcc.  The tests in question were zlib based.  a decompression by itself and a compression then decompression.  used both clang and llvm-gcc.  I preferred clang because the -m32 actually works on a 64 bit host.  For the test in question I found that NOT using -O2 (or -O3) produced the fastest code. linked the bytecode modules into one big module and performed one opt with standard optimisations, to get the fastest code.  llc was by default -O2 and that did help performance.

EDIT:

Interesting test between gcc and llvm/clang for mips.

```
void dummy ( unsigned int );
void dowait ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    for(ra=0x80000;ra;ra--) dummy(ra);
}
```

gcc produced:

```
9d006034 <dowait>:
9d006034:   27bdffe8    addiu   sp,sp,-24
9d006038:   afb00010    sw  s0,16(sp)
9d00603c:   afbf0014    sw  ra,20(sp)
9d006040:   3c100008    lui s0,0x8
9d006044:   02002021    move    a0,s0
9d006048:   0f40180a    jal 9d006028 <dummy>
9d00604c:   2610ffff    addiu   s0,s0,-1
9d006050:   1600fffd    bnez    s0,9d006048 <dowait+0x14>
9d006054:   02002021    move    a0,s0
9d006058:   8fbf0014    lw  ra,20(sp)
9d00605c:   8fb00010    lw  s0,16(sp)
9d006060:   03e00008    jr  ra
9d006064:   27bd0018    addiu   sp,sp,24
```

And llvm after assembling

```
9d006034 <dowait>:
9d006034:   27bdffe8    addiu   sp,sp,-24
9d006038:   afbf0014    sw  ra,20(sp)
9d00603c:   afb00010    sw  s0,16(sp)
9d006040:   3c020008    lui v0,0x8
9d006044:   34440000    ori a0,v0,0x0
9d006048:   2490ffff    addiu   s0,a0,-1
9d00604c:   0f40180a    jal 9d006028 <dummy>
9d006050:   00000000    nop
9d006054:   00102021    addu    a0,zero,s0
9d006058:   1600fffb    bnez    s0,9d006048 <dowait+0x14>
9d00605c:   00000000    nop
9d006060:   8fb00010    lw  s0,16(sp)
9d006064:   8fbf0014    lw  ra,20(sp)
9d006068:   27bd0018    addiu   sp,sp,24
9d00606c:   03e00008    jr  ra
9d006070:   00000000    nop
```

I say after assembling because I saw gnu-as do things like this

```
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    sw $a1,0($a0)
    jr $ra
    nop
```

and re-arrange the assembly for me:

```
9d00601c <PUT32>:
9d00601c:   03e00008    jr  ra
9d006020:   ac850000    sw  a1,0(a0)
9d006024:   00000000    nop
```

The difference between the llvm and gcc produced code is the instructions being placed in the branch defer slot.  I used clang and llc to produce assembly output then used binutils, gnu as, to create the binary.  So it is a curiosity that for my hand assembled code:

```
ori $sp,$sp,0x2000
jal notmain
nop
```

it optimized for me:

```
9d006004:   0f401820    jal 9d006080 <notmain>
9d006008:   37bd2000    ori sp,sp,0x2000
9d00600c:   00000000    nop
```

but the llc generated code

```
addiu   $16, $4, -1
jal dummy
nop
```

was not

```
9d006048:   2490ffff    addiu   s0,a0,-1
9d00604c:   0f40180a    jal 9d006028 <dummy>
9d006050:   00000000    nop
```

Comment: You get anywhere with this?  I am now just trying llvm and mips and getting relocation truncated to fit: R_MIPS_GOT16 and relocation truncated to fit: R_MIPS_CALL16 so I need to get llvm to not use gp or get ld to link it (using llvm to make assembler then binutils to take it to a binary).

Comment: ahh fixed it -relocation-model=static

Answer (score -1):

LLVM is generally better than GCC on x86, but I haven't found any benchmarks for MIPS. Because you're asking this question, I assume you have access to a MIPS machine, so why don't you compile the [Computer Language Benchmarks Game C code](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/c.php) with GCC and LLVM, and see which is faster. I'm guessing GCC will be, since the MIPS backend is relatively new, but the code is much cleaner, and I expect LLVM to eventually win.

Comment: better on x86 is a big assumtion, see http://leonardo-m.livejournal.com/77877.html it is not that obvious. About MIPS all I have is a old PS2 and a PSP and I cannot really compare since GCC backends have support for SIMD operations using it's internal VFPUs and the LLVM has no support for them yet.

Comment: The above link compares GCC -O3 to *JITed* LLVM.  This is hardly a fair comparison, either. LLVM can compile statically.

Comment: @nominolo, are you sure about "jited llvm" ? It does link itself to application , but does not rebuild any parts of it on-the-fly. For example, try to read this code of fibonacci function, which does use LLVM JIT http://www.cliff.biffle.org/software/llvm/ifibonacci.cpp

Comment: For my chess engine, gcc generated code by far outperforms LLVM. So your statement is not true in general, and actually I doubt it is based on any serious evidence.